# Convert HEX string to binary in groovy

Tags: groovy, binary, hex

Given a Hex string ="0A 02 00 25" how I can change to binary using groovy?

We have tried by using the BigInteger and by defining byte array.

Comment: Convert to Integer using Integer.valueOf("0A020025​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​", 16)​ then ByteBuffer to write to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Long.toBinaryString( Long.parseLong( '0A 02 00 25'.replaceAll("\\s",""), 16 ) )
```